# How to change tx_realurl_uniqalias for tt_news entry via backend?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, realurl, tt-news

I use useUniqueCache=1 for tt_news realurl config. If I make a new tt_news entry, the title will be written once into table tx_realurl_uniqalias.

Its fixed, if I change the title afterwards, its not changing uniqualias anymore. (As intended)

Now I have a typo. How to change it via TYPO3 Backend? I do not find any way via info > RealURL management. (using an admin account)

(via Database is not an option)

Answer (score 0):

Found it!: Info >  RealURL management > Unique Aliases > CLICK tt_news:

[image]
[image]